# "#" can not been used as separator of fields for read.table?

Tags: r, dataframe

I try to use "#" as the field separator to reading file into a data frame. But it looks like R can not recognize it. Why I can not use "#" as the field separator?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by field separator. Are you trying to read a text file into a data frame, and the field separator in the text file happens to be #?

Comment: Yes, that's what I intend to do.

Comment: does adding `comment=""` to your code help?  Normally `#` is a comment marker for `read.table()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See `?read.table`. You need to alter the `comment.char` argument as this is over-riding your attempts to set the delimiter to `#`.

Try `read.table(foo.txt, sep = "#", comment.char = "")`

Setting `comment.char = ""` turns of interpretation of comments (from `?read.table()`):

> `comment.char`: character: a character vector of length one containing a
>             single character or an empty string.  Use `""` to turn off
>             the interpretation of comments altogether.

Comment: Oh well, there's no shame if the great @GavinSimpson beats you by 55 seconds. :-)

Answer (score 6):

By default, `read.table` interprets `#` as a comment character. You can change this by specifying `sep="#"` and the comment.char as any single character that doesn't appear in your data. For example, set the comment character to an empty string, `comment.char=""`:

```
read.table(text="
A#B#C
1#2#3
4#5#6", header=TRUE, comment.char="", sep="#")

  A B C
1 1 2 3
2 4 5 6
```